# Tarea en segundo plano o asíncronica

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto realizado en asp net mvc c# y dentro de este, tengo un formulario que al hacer submit llama a otra función que tarda bastante tiempo en terminar.

Por lo cual, pensé que esta función debería ejecutar en segundo plano a la función (ejecutarla pero NO esperar a que termine) y que retorne un JSON, la función es muy grande, pero adjunto un ejemplo simplificado para replicar el comportamiento.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EnviarCorreos()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            EnviarCorreosCobranza(context);
        });

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Se enviaran los correos a la brevedad, le llegará una copia del mismo por mail." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Dentro de esa función utilizo todo el tiempo información del contexto para obtener usuario y demás datos de Identity, el primer problema que tuve fue que el HttpContext.Current era null dentro de la función hijo, por lo cual se lo asigné a mano.

En un principio funciona bien, pero vuelven a ser nulos una vez que la función padre termina su ejecución.

```
 private void EnviarCorreoCobranza(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Esta funcion recibe el context y lo asigna al contexto actual, porque se pierde cuando esta funcion es ejecutada
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current = context;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
        var id_unidad_facturacion = User.Identity.GetUsuario().ID_UNIDAD_FACTURACION; // Funciona (la función padre todavía esta viva)       
        
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);     
        id_unidad_facturacion = User.Identity.GetUsuario().ID_UNIDAD_FACTURACION; // No funciona, la función padre en este punto ya termino su ejecución.
    }
```

Estoy un poco mareado, intenté usar async await pero no me sirve, porque necesito retornar el json de respuesta SIN esperar a que el proceso hijo termine, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Intenta utilizando `Page.Context` o `Controller.HttpContext` en vez de `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Dentro del Task.Run() debes  guardar  la variable  "context" en otra variable y pasar  esta ultima a EnviarCorreoCobranza.  Algo así como: Task.Run(()=> { var  ctx = context; EnviarCorreoCobranza(ctx); }); Aparte que no deberías hacer esto:  System.Web.HttpContext.Current = context;

Comment: Por otro lado, lo mejor es  que pases los datos que necesita EnviarCorreosConbranza  para que éste no dependa del HttpContext, es decur que EnviarCorresoFacturación reciba como paramentros el id_unidad_facturación y este lo obtengas  previo a la llamada.